# Tag Synonym request: [ubuntu10.04] -> [10.04]

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

This new tag ([ubuntu10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu10.04)) appear to be exact same to [10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/10.04).

Should we synonimze this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that there was only one question using the tag - No is my answer.

BTW - the question was miss-tagged anyway, so I've removed [ubuntu10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu10.04) and tagged it correctly.

[ubuntu10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu10.04) will naturally disappear with time.

Comment: At 3:00 UTC to be exact.